# Distinct Sieves

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a list of integers, create a boolean mask such that the true indices can be used to filter the distinct values from the list. Which index is selected as the true one does not matter as long as only one of them is selected for each set of indices corresponding to identical values.

The input will be a non-empty list of non-negative integers in a format suitable for your language and the output will be a list of boolean values following the specification above. You are allowed to use your own definitions of truthy and falsy values in the output list.

In my examples below, I define `1` to be truthy and `0` to be falsy.

```
[5, 4, 7, 1]  Input
[1, 1, 1, 1]  Output
              Select only the values with with true indicies in the sieve
[5  4  7  1]  Contains zero duplicate values

[5, 9, 7, 5, 6, 0, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[   9, 7, 5, 6, 0   ]
```

### Test Cases

When there is an `or`, it means that there are multiple valid outputs. If there is a trailing ellipsis `...` after the `or`, it means that not all of the possible outputs were listed.

```
[0] = [1]

[55] = [1]

[32, 44] = [1, 1]

[0, 0] = [1, 0] or [0, 1]

[9001, 9001, 9001] = [1, 0 , 0] or [0, 1, 0] or [0, 0, 1]

[5, 4, 7, 1] = [1, 1, 1, 1]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] or
                     [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

[5, 9, 7, 5, 6, 0, 5] = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] or
                        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] or
                        [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

[0, 8, 6, 6, 3, 8, 7, 2] = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] or
                           [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] or
                           [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] or
                           [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

[45, 47, 47, 45, 24, 24, 24, 8, 47, 41, 47, 88]
= [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] or ...

[154, 993, 420, 154, 154, 689, 172, 417, 790, 175, 790, 790, 154, 172, 175, 175, 420, 417, 154, 175, 172, 175, 172, 993, 689, 993, 993, 790]
= [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] or ...
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution wins.
- Builtins are allowed!
- You are allowed to use your own definitions of truthy and falsy values in the output list. If you choose to do so, please state your definitions.
- The input will be a non-empty list of non-negative integers.
- You are free to choose between outputting only one of the sieves or multiple or even all of them. As long as each sieve is valid, it will be accepted.

Comment: For `[0, 8, 6, 6, 3, 8, 7, 2]`, should `[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` be added to the list of valid outputs?

Comment: Does *your own definitions of truthy and falsy values* refer to the language or can we choose freely? Do they have to be consistent?

Comment: @atlasologist Thanks for catching the typo

Comment: @Dennis You are free to define your own boolean values, they do not have to be the same as the language you choose, but you have to be consistent with your own definitions. Instead of 1 and 0 for true and false in my examples, I could have done negative values as false and non-negative (zero or positive) values as true.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. By consistent, I meant if there has to be a *single* truthy value or if there can be several.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## MATL, <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 4 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Luis*
*2 bytes saved thanks to @Dennis*

```
&=Rs
```

We define `1` to be truthy and all other values as falsey

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Jj1Scw&input=WzEgMiAzIDMgMiA0XQ)

[All test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YCAgICAgICAgJSBMb29wIHRocm91Z2ggYWxsIGlucHV0cwomPVJzCkRUICAgICAgICUgRGlzcGxheSBhbmQgZ28gdG8gdGhlIG5leHQgdGVzdGNhc2U&input=WzBdCls1NV0KWzMyLCA0NF0KWzAsIDBdCls5MDAxLCA5MDAxLCA5MDAxXQpbNSwgNCwgNywgMV0KWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDMsIDVdCls1LCA5LCA3LCA1LCA2LCAwLCA1XQpbMCwgOCwgNiwgNiwgMywgOCwgNywgMl0KWzQ1LCA0NywgNDcsIDQ1LCAyNCwgMjQsIDI0LCA4LCA0NywgNDEsIDQ3LCA4OF0KWzE1NCwgOTkzLCA0MjAsIDE1NCwgMTU0LCA2ODksIDE3MiwgNDE3LCA3OTAsIDE3NSwgNzkwLCA3OTAsIDE1NCwgMTcyLCAxNzUsIDE3NSwgNDIwLCA0MTcsIDE1NCwgMTc1LCAxNzIsIDE3NSwgMTcyLCA5OTMsIDY4OSwgOTkzLCA5OTMsIDc5MF0)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input array
&=  % 2D array of equality comparisons
R   % Get the upper triangular portion
s   % Sum down the columns
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: 1 byte fewer: `&=Rs1=`

Comment: @LuisMendo Ha I was literally just playing with that approach!

Comment: The OP has clarified what truthy and falsy mean in this challenge. If you define **1** as truthy and everything else as falsy, you can drop the `l=`.

Comment: Great use. The intent was to avoid having to add a filtering step and now you've matched Dennis' Jelly solution.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ĠṪ€Ṭ
```

Favors last occurrences. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xKDhuarigqzhuaw&input=&args=WzUsIDksIDcsIDUsIDYsIDAsIDVd) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xKDhuarigqzhuawKw4figqxH&input=&args=WzBdLCBbNTVdLCBbMzIsIDQ0XSwgWzAsIDBdLCBbOTAwMSwgOTAwMSwgOTAwMV0sIFs1LCA0LCA3LCAxXSwgWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDMsIDVdLCBbNSwgOSwgNywgNSwgNiwgMCwgNV0sIFswLCA4LCA2LCA2LCAzLCA4LCA3LCAyXSwgWzQ1LCA0NywgNDcsIDQ1LCAyNCwgMjQsIDI0LCA4LCA0NywgNDEsIDQ3LCA4OF0sIFsxNTQsIDk5MywgNDIwLCAxNTQsIDE1NCwgNjg5LCAxNzIsIDQxNywgNzkwLCAxNzUsIDc5MCwgNzkwLCAxNTQsIDE3MiwgMTc1LCAxNzUsIDQyMCwgNDE3LCAxNTQsIDE3NSwgMTcyLCAxNzUsIDE3MiwgOTkzLCA2ODksIDk5MywgOTkzLCA3OTBd).

#### How it works

```
ĠṪ€Ṭ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Ġ     Group; paritition the indices of A according to their corresponding values.
 Ṫ€   Tail each; select the last index of each group.
   Ṭ  Untruth; generate a Boolean array with 1's at the specified indices.
```

Comment: Would this not chop off the zeroes at the end?

Comment: There can't be a zero at the end, because we select the *last* occurrence of each unique integer.

Comment: That's clever .

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3, <s>47</s> <s>35</s> <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```
lambda n:[n.pop(0)in n for x in n*1]
```

Pops the first item from the list, checks if it exists elsewhere in the list, and inserts `True` or `False` into a new list.

For this function, `False` indicates a distinct value, and `True` is otherwise (`True=0` and `False=1`)

*Thanks to Dennis for a ton of bytes*

Original, 47 bytes:

```
lambda n:[(1,0)[n.pop()in n]for x in[1]*len(n)]
```

[Try it](https://repl.it/C8Nk/1)

Comment: `lambda n:[1-(n.pop()in n)for x in n*1]` saves a few bytes.

Comment: The OP has clarified that the truthy value doesn't actually have to be truthy, so `lambda n:[n.pop()in n for x in n*1]` works as well.

Comment: The new version had me lost for a bit until I realized it used the negated values like xnor did for truthy and falsy.

Comment: You need to do `.pop(0)` or the mask comes out reversed.

Comment: That not what xnor meant. `.pop()` processes the *last* element first, so the are in reversed order.

Comment: @Dennis D'oh! I was trying to flip the boolean, but yeah, I see the whole list is reversed. I just re-read the specs. I'll edit the change in. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the OP said so in [this comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84297/distinct-sieves/84303?noredirect=1#comment206327_84297).

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
.eqxQb
```

Outputs a list of bools (`True` and `False`). Checks for each element in the input, if its index is equal to the index of the first occurence of the value. In other words, this is checking if each element is the first occurence.

In pythonic pseudocode:

```
.e      enumerated_map(lambda b,k:    # maps with b as value and k as index
  q       equal(
   xQb      Q.index(b),
            k),                       # implicit lambda variable
          Q)                          # implicit argument to map
```

[Test it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.eqxQb&input=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%5D%0A%5B55%5D%0A%5B32%2C%2044%5D%0A%5B0%2C%200%5D%0A%5B9001%2C%209001%2C%209001%5D%0A%5B5%2C%204%2C%207%2C%201%5D%0A%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%203%2C%205%5D%0A%5B5%2C%209%2C%207%2C%205%2C%206%2C%200%2C%205%5D%0A%5B0%2C%208%2C%206%2C%206%2C%203%2C%208%2C%207%2C%202%5D%0A%5B45%2C%2047%2C%2047%2C%2045%2C%2024%2C%2024%2C%2024%2C%208%2C%2047%2C%2041%2C%2047%2C%2088%5D%0A%5B154%2C%20993%2C%20420%2C%20154%2C%20154%2C%20689%2C%20172%2C%20417%2C%20790%2C%20175%2C%20790%2C%20790%2C%20154%2C%20172%2C%20175%2C%20175%2C%20420%2C%20417%2C%20154%2C%20175%2C%20172%2C%20175%2C%20172%2C%20993%2C%20689%2C%20993%2C%20993%2C%20790%5D&debug=1)

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com), 2 bytes

```
~:
```

This was where the idea for this challenge originated from. The builtin `~:` is called `Nub-Sieve` in J and creates a boolean list that performs the operation described in the challenge. Here, `1` represents `true` and `0` represents `false`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Code:

```
v¹ykN>Qˆ
```

Explanation:

```
y         # For each in the array
 ¹yk      # Get the index of that element in the array
    N>Q   # And see if it's equal to the index
       ˆ  # Add to the global array and implicitly output
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dsK5eWtOPlHLhg&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDMsIDMsIDVd).

Answer (score 4):

### C#, 63 bytes

```
int[]l(List<int> i)=>i.Select((m,n)=>i.IndexOf(m)-n).ToArray();
```

I could also make it return 1 or 0 and therby make the parameter and return type the same one therby allowing me to make this a lambda expression by itself?

*some guidance would be appreciated*

**same type code**

```
    public static List<int>l(List<int>i){
        return i.Select((m,n)=>i.IndexOf(m)==n?1:0).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: if you define truthy to be 0 and falsy to be anything else you can replace the ==n with -n and return a int[]

Comment: thats a great idea

Comment: also use expression bodied function int[]l(List<int>i)=>i.Select((m,n)=>i.IndexOf(m)-n).ToArray();

Comment: oh my god, thats saving so many bytes in my answers from now on. thank you so much

Comment: Can you provide an example on .NetFiddle?

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 6 bytes

```
⍳∘⍴∊⍳⍨
```

[Try it](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%u2373%u2218%u2374%u220A%u2373%u2368%29%205%209%207%205%206%200%205&run)

Explanation:

```
   ⍳⍨  For each character in the string, get the index of its first occurrence
⍳∘⍴     Make a list 1 .. length of input
  ∊    Check if each index is present
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l and[l.pop(0)in l]+f(l)
```

Uses `True` as the falsy value and `False` for the truthy value. Marks the last appearance of each element.

Selects the first element only if it doesn't appear among the remaining elements, then recurses to the rest of the list as long as it's non-empty. The `l.pop(0)` extracts the first element while also removing it.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 23 bytes

```
(\d+)((?!.* \1\b))?
$#2
```

Input is a space-separated list. (Actually, other formats like `[1, 2, 3]` will also work as long as there's a space in front of each number except the first.)

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KFxkKykoKD8hLiogXDFcYikpPwokIzI&input=MAo1NQozMiA0NAowIDAKOTAwMSA5MDAxIDkwMDEKNSA0IDcgMQoxIDIgMyA0IDMgNQo1IDkgNyA1IDYgMCA1CjAgOCA2IDYgMyA4IDcgMgo0NSA0NyA0NyA0NSAyNCAyNCAyNCA4IDQ3IDQxIDQ3IDg4CjE1NCA5OTMgNDIwIDE1NCAxNTQgNjg5IDE3MiA0MTcgNzkwIDE3NSA3OTAgNzkwIDE1NCAxNzIgMTc1IDE3NSA0MjAgNDE3IDE1NCAxNzUgMTcyIDE3NSAxNzIgOTkzIDY4OSA5OTMgOTkzIDc5MA) (Works on multiple linefeed-separated test cases at once.)

We simply turn each element into `0` if there's another copy of it later on in the input and into `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 40 bytes

```
$a=@();$args[0]|%{(1,0)[$_-in$a];$a+=$_}
```

Creates an empty array `$a`. Then we take the input list via `$args[0]` and pipe that into a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration we select either `1` or `0` from a pseudo-ternary based on whether the current element is in `$a` or not. Those selections are left on the pipeline. We then add the current element into the array `$a`. The pipeline elements are gathered up, and output as an array is implicit.

#### Example:

*(output here with a newline separator, since that's the default `.ToString()` for an array)*

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\distinct-sieves.ps1 1,2,3,4,1,3,5,7
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
f=a=>a.map((e,i)=>i-a.indexOf(e))
```

Zero is truthy and other numbers are falsy.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>53</s> 31 bytes

*Thanks to miles for giving me an idea that saved 22 bytes.*

```
s[[;;x++]]~FreeQ~#&/@(x=0;s=#)&
```

Comment: How about using `MapIndexed` over the previous sublists? `MapIndexed[s[[;;#-1&@@#2]]~FreeQ~#&,s=#]&` takes 41 bytes.

Comment: @miles Ohh, that's much better (and I improved it a bit more ;))

Comment: Oo that's a nice way to shorten `MapIndexed` for this case and you don't even have to extract or decrement the index

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5

```
push@o,map{$b=pop@a;(grep{/^$b$/}@a)?1:0}(1..~~@a);
```

Comment: 1. `..` provides scalar context, so you shouldn't need `~~`. 2. `grep` returns truthy/falsy, so you shouldn't need `?1:0`. 3. `grep/.../,@a` is shorter than `grep{/.../}@a`. 4. You shouldn't need the final `;`. 5. You shouldn't need the parentheses around `1..@a`. 6. You don't show where the input is coming from or the output is going to: see http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 96 bytes

```java
void s(int[]a){for(int i=0,j,n=a.length,b=1;i<n;a[i++]=b,b=1)for(j=i+1;j<n;)b=a[i]==a[j++]?0:b;}
```

Modifies the array in-place. Favours the last occurrence.

The truthy value is `1` while the falsey value is `0`.

[Verify all testcases](http://ideone.com/UPpjKx).

Ungolfed:

```java
void sieve(int[]a){
    int n = a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int b = 1;
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i] == a[j]){
                b = 0;
            }
        }
        a[i] = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 11 bytes

```
;╗ñ`i@╜í=`M
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KVl8OxYGlA4pWcw609YE0&input=WzUsIDksIDcsIDUsIDYsIDAsIDVd)

Explanation:

```
;╗ñ`i@╜í=`M
;╗           save a copy of input in reg0
  ñ          enumerate
   `i@╜í=`M  for each (index, value) pair:
    i@         flatten, swap
      ╜í       first index in input of value
        =      compare equality
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
F@oq
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=F%40oq&input=%5B9001%2C+9002%2C+9001%2C+9003%2C+9002%5D&warnings=0)

```
     - o = 0 #(Implicit)
F    - for i in input:
 @   -   input.index(i)
   q -  ^==V
  o  -   o+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>29</s> 27  bytes

```
f a=[elem x t|x:t<-tails a]
```

Uses `False` as true, `True` as false value:

```
λ> let f a=[elem x t|x:t<-tails a] in f [5, 9, 7, 5, 6, 0, 5]
[True,False,False,True,False,False,False]
```

You might have to `import Data.List` to use `tails` but,  [tryhaskell.org](https://tryhaskell.org/) runs the code as is.

Comment: No need for the outer parenthesis. `\a->[...]` is a proper function. If in doubt, give it a name: `f a=[...]`.

Comment: @nimi couldn't call it without the parentheses. but giving it name works, thanks a lot.

Comment: I don’t like this justification of omitting `import Data.List` very much. **a.** is a very slippery slope as you could put any amount of imports (or even definitions!) in your GHCi config. **b.** treats tryhaskell.org as an authoritative implementation of the Haskell language, but it really isn’t one. (Again, what if I create my own try-Haskell-online environment that comes with all the imports and definitions golfers could ever want? Is that still really “Haskell”?)

Comment: I was told here once that if there is any platform that runs the  code as is, then that code is acceptable. I don't know what the exact rules are, I go by what I'm told. I think yes, if your site is available 24/7, and runs standard Haskell, why not. But you're right about the first one, I removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 39 bytes

- accepts all atomic values (boolean, integer, float, string)
  except for values evaluating to false (false, 0, "") and numeric strings ("1" equals 1)
- flags first occurence

**new version** (program, 37+2 bytes)
<sup>beats Java and (now again) C#. Even almost beats Python now. Happy.</sup>

```
<?foreach($a as$v)$u[$v]=print$u[$v]|0;
```

- +6 for PHP>=5.4, +16-3 for a function
- prints undelimited list of `0` (true) and `1` (false)
  insert `!` after `print` to invert
- usage: set `register_globals=On`, `short_open_tags=On` and `error_reporting=0` in `php.ini` for `php-cgi`
  then call `php-cgi -f <filename> a[]=<value1> a[]=<value2> ...;echo""`;
- for PHP>=5.4: replace `$a` with `$_GET[a]` (+6), set `short_open_tags=On` and `error_reporting=0`
- or replace `$a` with `array_slice($argv,1)` (+19), remove `<?`  (-2)
  and call `php -d error_reporting=0 -r '<code>' <value1> <value2> ...;echo""`

**old version** (function, 62 bytes)

```
function f($a){foreach($a as$v)$u[$v]=1|$m[]=$u[$v];return$m;}
```

- returns array of `false` for true and `true` for false; (ouput as empty string or `1`)
  insert `!` after `$m[]=` to invert
- There is another way for a qualified function with 55 bytes, too.

**tests** (on old version)

```
function out($a){if(!is_array($a))return$a;$r=[];foreach($a as$v)$r[]=out($v);return'['.join(',',$r).']';}
function test($x,$e,$y){static $h='<table border=1><tr><th>input</th><th>output</th><th>expected</th><th>ok?</th></tr>';echo"$h<tr><td>",out($x),'</td><td>',out($y),'</td><td>',out($e),'</td><td>',(strcmp(out($y),out($e))?'N':'Y'),"</td></tr>";$h='';}
$samples=[
    [0],[1],    [55],[1],    [32,44],[1,1],    [9001,9001,9001],[1,false,false],
    [5,4,7,1],[1,1,1,1],    [1,2,3,4,3,5],[1,1,1,1,false,1],
    [5,9,7,5,6,0,5],[1,1,1,false,1,1,false],    [0,8,6,6,3,8,7,2],[1,1,1,false,1,false,1,1],
    [45,47,47,45,24,24,24,8,47,41,47,88],[1,1,'','',1,'','',1,'',1,'',1],
    [154,993,420,154,154,689,172,417,790,175,790,790,154,172,175,
        175,420,417,154,175,172,175,172,993,689, 993,993,790],
        array_merge([1,1,1,false,false,1,1,1,1,1],array_fill(0,18,false))
];
for($i=count($samples);$i--;--$i)for($j=count($samples[$i]);$j--;)$samples[$i][$j]=!$samples[$i][$j];
while($samples)
{
    $a=array_shift($samples);
    $em=array_shift($samples);
    test($a,$em,$ym=s($a));
    $eu=[];foreach($em as$i=>$f)if($f)$eu[]=$a[$i];
    $yu=[];foreach($ym as$i=>$f)if($f)$yu[]=$a[$i];
#   sort($eu); sort($yu);
    test('unique values',$eu,$yu);
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 242 bytes

Admittedly an overkill solution, as it works on *any* standard container of *any* ordered type:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>
#include<set>
template<class T>auto f(T a){using V=typename T::value_type;std::set<V>s;std::list<bool>r;std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),std::back_inserter(r),[&](V m){return s.insert(m).second;});return r;}
```

### Ungolfed:

(and further generalised)

```
template<class T>
auto f(T a)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using V=typename T::value_type;
    std::set<V>s;
    std::list<bool>r;
    std::transform(begin(a),end(a),std::back_inserter(r),[&](V m){return s.insert(m).second;});
    return r;
}
```

### Test suite:

```
int test(const std::list<bool>& expected, const auto& x) { return f(x) != expected; }
#include<array>
#include<chrono>
#include<forward_list>
#include<initializer_list>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
int main()
{
    return 0
        + test({},            std::vector<short>{})
        + test({1},           std::array<int,1>{})
        + test({1},           std::vector<char>{55})
        + test({true,true},   std::vector<unsigned>{32,44})
        + test({1,0},         std::list<std::string>{"zero", "zero"})
        + test({1,0,0},       std::vector<long>{9001,9001,9001})
        + test({1,1,1,1},     std::array<char,4>{5,4,7,1})
        + test({1,1,1,1,0,1}, std::initializer_list<std::string>{"one","two","three","four","three","five"})
        + test({1,0,1,0,0},   std::forward_list<std::chrono::seconds>{60s, 1min, 3600s, 60min, 1h});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL 52 bytes

```
DECLARE @ TABLE(i int identity, v int)
INSERT @ values(1),(2),(3),(4),(3),(5)

SELECT i/max(i)over(partition by v)FROM @ ORDER BY i
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507966/distinct-sieves)**

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 + [Perligata](//metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Romana::Perligata), 343 bytes

315 bytes, plus 28 for `-MLingua::Romana::Perligata`

Use as `perl -MLingua::Romana::Perligata foo.pl`; input (from stdin) and output (to stdout) are underscore-separated strings of decimal integers. Tested on Strawberry 5.20.2 with version 0.6 of Perligata; I don't know whether it works with Perligata version 0.50.

```
huic vestibulo perlegementum da.qis _ scindementa da.dum qis fac sic
ao qis decumulamentum da.ao aum tum nullum addementum da.meo io.meo ro.per ium in qis fac sic
si ium tum aum aequalitas fac sic ro I da cis cis
ro nullum tum non rum addementum da.capita bis rum cis
per in bis fac sic hoc tum _ egresso scribe cis
```

---

Obviously this is clear as a bell. In case it's not, run it with `-MLingua::Romana::Perligata=converte` instead of `-MLingua::Romana::Perligata`, and `perl` will, instead of running the script, output a translation into regular Perl:

```
 $_ = Lingua::Romana::Perligata::getline (*STDIN );
 @q = split ( '_');
while (@q) { $a = pop (@q );
 $a =  ($a + 0);
my $i ;
my $r ;
for $i (@q) {if ( ($i eq $a)) { $r = 1}
}
;
 $r =  (0 +  ! ($r));
unshift (@b, $r)}
;
for $_ (@b) {print (STDOUT $_, '_')}
```

For a token-by-token analysis, use `-MLingua::Romana::Perligata=discribe`.

---

Golfing notes:

- Undocumented (but unsurprising), you don't need a space after `.`.
- (Also unsurprising,) `scinde` doesn't need a second argument, and uses `hoc`.
- I had to use `ao aum tum nullum addementum da` because I couldn't get `morde` to work.
- Similarly, I used `per ium in qis... ro I da` because I couldn't get `vanne` to work.
- Instead of `huic vestibulo perlegementum da`, I tried `-pMLingua::Romana::Perligata`, but couldn't get it to work, either.

---

Just for kicks (although this whole answer was just for kicks):

- After cleaning it up to `Huic vestibulo perlegementum da. Qis lacunam scindementa da. Dum qis fac sic ao qis decumulamentum da. Ao aum tum nullum addementum da. Meo io. Meo ro. Per ium in qis fac sic si ium tum aum aequalitas fac sic ro I da cis cis. Ro nullum tum non rum addementum da. Capita bis rum cis. Per in bis fac sic hoc tum lacunam egresso scribe cis.`, Google Translate gives `This court perlegementum grant. QIS gap scindementa grant. While QIS QIS decumulamentum do so ao da. Ao sum and no addementum grant. My io. My ro. Through ium in QIS do so if the sum ium equality do so ro 1 from cis. Ro was not any rum addementum grant. The heads of the bis side. Write, do so as soon as he at that time that in the gap by the Kish was taken.`.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 19 bytes

```
..|:i;{i,\i\-:i,-}%
```

Explanation!

```
..|:i;{i,\i\-:i,-}% #Distinct sieve
..                  #Duplicate twice. Stack is [A A A]
  |                 #Binary OR. Removes duplicates. Stack is [A (A|A)]
   :i;              #Call this A|A i, and remove it from the stack. [A], i=A|A
      {          }% #Block notation. For each element in the top array, perform this on it.
      {i,        }% #Size of i. Element in array is [E (i,)].
      {  \       }% #Swap the top two elements. [(i,) E]
      {   i\     }% #Put i in the actual second position. [(i,) i E]
      {     -    }% #Remove all instances of the top element from the second. [(i,) (i-E)]
      {      :i  }% #This (i-E) is our new i (for the next loop).
      {        , }% #Size of topmost element (either i, or i,-1 if index was found).
      {         -}% #Subtract. This gives us 1 if E was removed from i, 0 otherwise.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbapgqWCuYKpgpmCgYBr7X0@vxirTujpTJyYzRtcqU0e3VvX/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 41 bytes

```
.[:range(length)+1]|[.[:-1][]!=.[-1]]|all
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/18v2qooMS89VSMnNS@9JENT2zC2JhooqGsYGx2raKsXDWTE1iTm5Pz/H22oo2Cko2Cso2ACJk1jAQ)

Takes an array, outputs a stream of jq booleans corresponding to its distinct sieve.

-10 from ovs.

Comment: If you use vectorized `!=` and `all` instead of `index` and `not`, you don't need the assignment: `.[:range(length)+1]|[.[:-1][]!=.[-1]]|all`

Comment: great method to remove the variable. Thanks.